# Image Adjustment wipes out overplots?

Tags: geographics, graphics

I'm having a problem where when I display lines over an image (using `Show`) it works fine, but if I adjust the image colors first (using either `ImageAdjust[]` or `Lighter[]`) the lines vanish.  Am I misunderstanding how image adjustment works? Here's a simplified example:

```
g = Graphics @@ GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" -> GeoPosition[{-22, 110}]}, GeoGridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1, GeoBackground -> "Satellite"];
h = Lighter[g, 1];
l1 = Plot[.18 x - .4, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, Axes -> False];
Show[g, l1]
Show[h, l1]
```

Why does the second show not have the overplotted line?

Thanks much for any help you can provide...

[image: example of overplots]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `l1` is not visible in `Show[h, l1]` is that `h` has a vastly different plot range than `l1`:

```
PlotRange /@ {g, l1, Show[h]}
```

> {{{-0.999874, 0.999371}, {-0.999977, 0.999573}}, {{-1.5708, 
>         1.5708}, {-0.682743, -0.117257}}, {{0., 360.}, {0., 360.}}}

```
 Row[Show[#, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300]& /@ {h, g}]
```

[image]

To see `h` and `l1` together, you can rescale `h` to the plot range of `g` using [`RescalingTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RescalingTransform.html):

```
Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, 
    RescalingTransform[PlotRange[Show[h]], PlotRange[g]]] &, 
  Show@h , {1}], l1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]